# How to put data from JSON into a pickerview in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to put the data from the json link into my pickerview and the selection will ve shown in the text below it. I found similar examples but I could not adapt them into my code. When I do that with List, it works but I want it with pickerview style.

```
    @State var selectedFrameworkIndex = 0
    
    @ObservedObject var cityfetch = cityFetcher()

    NavigationView{
    VStack{
  
                    Section{
                   Picker(selection: $selectedFrameworkIndex, label: Text("")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< cityfetch.cities.count, id: \.self) {
     
                        Text(self.cityfetch.cities[$0].name)
                       }
                   }.padding(.trailing, 50)
                    }
                   Text("Your choice: \(cityfetch.cities[selectedFrameworkIndex])")
                        .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .regular, design: .rounded))
                    
                }
    }

    My cityfetcher class is as following..
    
    class cityFetcher : ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var cities = [city]()
    
    init() {
        loadCity()
    }
    func loadCity(){
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ozdemirburak/4821a26db048cc0972c1beee48a408de/raw/4754e5f9d09dade2e6c461d7e960e13ef38eaa88/cities_of_turkey.json")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            do{
                let cities = try JSONDecoder().decode([city].self, from: data!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.cities = cities
                }
                    
                
            }   catch{
                print("Error")
            }
        }.resume()
        
        
    }
    
}

    struct city :Identifiable, Decodable{
    let name : String
    let id : Int
    let region : String
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug with the `Picker` element, adding an id for the Picker element seems to solve the problem.

```
Picker(selection: $selectedFrameworkIndex, label: Text("")) {
   ForEach(0 ..< cityfetch.cities.count, id: \.self) {
      Text(self.cityfetch.cities[$0].name)
   }
}
.padding(.trailing, 50)
.id(UUID())
```

In order for the text to get updated I would suggest adding a property to return the selected city name:

```
var selectedCityName: String? {
    if !cityfetch.cities.isEmpty && selectedFrameworkIndex < cityfetch.cities.count {
        return cityfetch.cities[selectedFrameworkIndex].name
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Then change the Text element to:

```
Text("Your choice: \(selectedCityName ?? "")").font(.system(size: 20, weight: .regular, design: .rounded))
```

Comment: It worked when I put .id(UUID()) but I still can not get the city I chose write into my text. Still there is a problem in Text("Your choice: \(cityfetch.cities[selectedFrameworkIndex])") part of the code.

Comment: @Ozan Sorry for the late update. Please check if it helps.